# Type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo' threw an exception Avalonia

Tags: c#, skiasharp, avaloniaui

Full traceback

```
$ dotnet run avgui.cs
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo' threw an exception.
 ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libSkiaSharp' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibSkiaSharp: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at SkiaSharp.SkiaApi.sk_colortype_get_default_8888()
   at SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Avalonia.Skia.PlatformRenderInterface..ctor(ISkiaGpu skiaGpu, Nullable`1 maxResourceBytes) in /_/src/Skia/Avalonia.Skia/PlatformRenderInterface.cs:line 27
   at Avalonia.Skia.SkiaPlatform.Initialize(SkiaOptions options) in /_/src/Skia/Avalonia.Skia/SkiaPlatform.cs:line 20
   at Avalonia.SkiaApplicationExtensions.<>c__0`1.<UseSkia>b__0_0() in /_/src/Skia/Avalonia.Skia/SkiaApplicationExtensions.cs:line 20
   at Avalonia.Controls.AppBuilderBase`1.Setup() in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/AppBuilderBase.cs:line 304
   at Avalonia.Controls.AppBuilderBase`1.SetupWithLifetime(IApplicationLifetime lifetime) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/AppBuilderBase.cs:line 179
   at Avalonia.ClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetimeExtensions.StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime[T](T builder, String[] args, ShutdownMode shutdownMode) in /_/src/Avalonia.Controls/ApplicationLifetimes/ClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime.cs:line 147
   at gui_av_c.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/ibrahim/C#/gui_av_c/Program.cs:line 13
```

avgui.cs

```cs
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Interactivity;
using Avalonia.Markup.Xaml;

namespace AvaloniaApplication1
{
    public class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button)sender;
            button.Content = "Hello, Avalonia!";
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I setuped the `gui_av_c` directory.

```
~/C#$ mkdir gui_av_c
~/C#$ cd gui_av_c/
~/C#/gui_av_c$ dotnet new avalonia.app
The template "Avalonia .NET Core App" was created successfully.
```

**What I have tried:**

```
$ sudo apt install skia-sharp
$ sudo apt install libskiasharp
$ dotnet add package SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux
```

Putting `libSkiaSharp.so` in `\usr\lib`

```
$ lddtree /usr/lib/libSkiaSharp.so
libSkiaSharp.so => /usr/lib/libSkiaSharp.so (interpreter => none)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1
        libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
            libpng16.so.16 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
            libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Comment: `lddtree /path/to/libSkiaSharp.so`

Comment: @kekekeks i edited the question with the output of the above command and the error i get if I do `dotnet run agvui.cs` again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using .NET SDK from snap. When you run your app with such SDK, snap will start your program in a sandbox environment (that nobody has asked for, especially for an SDK tool, but it does that anyway) with its own root file system without native dependencies required by Avalonia. Nothing you install on the main system will affect said sandbox. It just won't work.

Purge snap-installed .NET SDK from your system (preferably alongside with snap itself) and install using instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2004- :

```sh
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb

sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

Comment: after I remove `dotnet-sdk` from snap and download from microsoft it gives me this output
```bash
$ dotnet

Command 'dotnet' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install dotnet-sdk
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/dotnet` is a part of the `dotnet-host` package. Make sure that it's installed. Also check the output of `which dotnet`, there could be some leftovers from the snap-installed version. Canonical does _heavy_ promotion of their snap tool, so it's harder to get rid of it with each Ubuntu release (which is one of the reasons I'm considering to move to Debian after using Ubuntu for 10+ years on desktop and servers)

Comment: `which dotnet` doesn't give any output and how do I install dotnet-host

Comment: Are you sure that you've executed `sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0`? `dotnet-host` package should get installed as a dependency.

Comment: nvm it was some problem with a PPA which causing problem at sudo apt update

Answer (score 0):

You can try install `SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies` NuGet package **instead of** `SkiaSharp`. This solved our problem with "... Unable to load shared library 'libSkiaSharp' or one of its dependencies."

Also if you run the app in a docker container and you want to keep `SkiaSharp` Nuget package you will need to install font config:

```
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libfontconfig1 \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```